# How can i get an image from a pcap file?

Tags: c#, pcap, winpcap

I wrote a basic c# wrapper for winpcap to capture packets from an interface and saving them to a dump file. Now i wanna get images in that pcap files. Is there a c# library for this purpose?

Comment: Wow, this seems... ambitious :) - do you know what protocol the images are being sent over? Is it HTTP (web browsing) traffic you want to be monitoring?

Comment: it was just an example :) i want to interpret all the data that pcap file has. For start i want to get just http images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [DriftNet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~chris/driftnet/)

> Inspired by EtherPEG (though, not owning an Apple Macintosh, I've never actually seen it in operation), Driftnet is a program which listens to network traffic and picks out images from TCP streams it observes. Fun to run on a host which sees lots of web traffic.

Comment: sorry i need a microsoft one since im developing my application with c#.net.

Comment: Or its windows cousin, VLADescu: http://www.rostudent.com/robert/VLADescu.html - very cool!

Comment: This is a programming QA site. Head over to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx and code away :)